# How to smart reindent and reformat code in VSCode?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

Using IntelliJ, if you type or copy code and the indentation or formatting is not correct, you can easily press Shift Command L and it fixes indentation and formatting. This works on all languages I've tried (python, javascript, html/css, etc)

Is there a way to do the same using VSCode but can't find any way to do it.

**IntelliJ Before**
Improper space on parenthesis, unnecessary space between colon and parenthesis, too little space between lines, and incorrect indentation on the if True line.
[image: IntelliJ Before]

**IntelliJ After**
It used PEP8 code standards and fixed all the issues mentioned.
[image: IntelliJ After Code Formatting]

Is there a way to do this on VSCode?

Answer (score -4):

When I use Python or any language in that indentation matters I hit enter after the `:` then it put the cursor in the right place.

Comment: This only re-indent the lines blindly to the left or the right.  It doesn't correct code formatting issues as described.

Comment: when i use python or any language that indentation matters i hit enter after the ' : ' then it put me in the right place

Comment: Cain that is correct, as you type/press enter.  But sometimes you open existing code or paste it and it is incorrect. This doesn't get fixed by pressing enter.